# How to compare types of different, generic HLists?

Tags: scala, shapeless

So I have a user defined input of `keys`, and the user is also expected to provide serializers for these keys. I am trying to statically ensure that the serializers provided work with the user provided types. Example user usage would be something like:

```
case class Keys(key1: String, key2: Int)

val keys = Keys("Foo", 2)
val keyDescriptor = (StringSerializer, IntSerializer)

toSerializedKeys(keys, keyDescriptor)
```

but I would like something like this to fail at compile time:

```
val keys = Keys("Foo", 2)
val keyDescriptor = (StringSerializer, StringSerializer)

toSerializedKeys(keys, keyDescriptor)
```

To abstract over arity and attempt to provide compile time type matching on the keys/serializers I'm trying to use shapeless. My current solution works fine given explicit `HLists`. But as soon as I try to apply this to generic `HList`s things fall apart.

Current solution:

Assume we have the following user provided serializers:

```
trait SerializerFn[T] {
  def toBytes(t: T): ByteBuffer
}

object StringSerializerFn extends SerializerFn[String] {
  override def toBytes(t: String): ByteBuffer = ???
}

object IntSerializerFn extends SerializerFn[Int] {
  override def toBytes(t: Int): ByteBuffer = ???
}
```

I currently create a type class, helper function, and instances to handle serialization of `HList`s:

```
trait Serializer[HA <: HList, HB <: HList] {
  def toBufs(keys: HA)(fns: HB): List[ByteBuffer]
}

object Serializer extends SerializerInstances {
  def toBufs[HA <: HList, HB <: HList](keys: HA)(fns: HB)(
    implicit 
    serializer: Serializer[HA, HB]
  ): List[ByteBuffer] = {
    serializer.toBufs(keys)(fns)
  }
}

trait SerializerInstances {
  implicit val hnilSerializer: Serializer[HNil, HNil] =
    new Serializer[HNil, HNil] {
      override def toBufs(keys: HNil)(fns: HNil): List[ByteBuffer] = Nil
    }

  implicit def hconsSerializer[H, Fn <: SerializerFn[H], TA <: HList, TB <: HList](
    implicit
    hconsSerializer: Serializer[TA, TB],
  ): Serializer[H :: TA, Fn :: TB] =
    new Serializer[H :: TA, Fn :: TB] {
      override def toBufs(keys: H :: TA)(fns: Fn :: TB): List[ByteBuffer] =
        List(fns.head.toBytes(keys.head)) ::: hconsSerializer.toBufs(keys.tail)(fns.tail)
    }
}
```

The static type checking I'm going for here is happening in `hconsSerializer` where we restrict the head of both `HList`s to be an `H` and `SerializerFn[H]`, respectively.

And to test it, this compiles fine:

```
val testKeys = "3" :: "4" :: HNil
val testFns = StringSerializerFn :: StringSerializerFn :: HNil

val testSerializedKeys = Serializer.toBufs(testKeys)(testFns)
```

and as expected, this doesn't compile:

```
val testKeys = "3" :: "4" :: HNil
val testFns = StringSerializerFn :: IntSerializerFn :: HNil

val testSerializedKeys = Serializer.toBufs(testKeys)(testFns)
```

However, when trying to generalize this (so that we can actually use this in a constructor that we provide to users), things fall apart, (I've omitted the `Generic` conversion from the user provided `Product` to `HList` for brevity):

```
def toSerializedKeys[ReprA <: HList, ReprB <: HList](
  keys: ReprA,
  fns: ReprB
): List[ByteBuffer] = 
  Serializer.toBufs(keys)(fns)
```

For reference, intellij complains that the implicit `Serializer` can't be found, and explicitly passing `hconsSerializer` shows:

```
Required: Serializer[ ReprA, ReprB]
Found:    Serializer[Nothing :: HNil, Nothing :: HNil]
```

and Scalac says:

```
[error]  found   : [H, Fn <: com.twitter.beam.io.manhattan.SerializerFn[H], TA <: shapeless.HList, TB <: shapeless.HList]com.twitter.beam.io.manhattan.Serializer[H :: TA,Fn :: TB]
[error]  required: com.twitter.beam.io.manhattan.Serializer[ReprA,ReprB]
```

What kind of implicit evidence do I need to be able to perform this kind of recursive type checking on generic `HList`s? Is accomplishing something like this even possible? I'm new to Shapeless.

---

Also, if comparing `HList` types like this isn't possible. Another solution could be something that allowed the user to define *individual* implicit key serializers, instead of a full `KeyDescriptor` that we convert to an `HList`, e.g something like:

```
implicit val intSerializer = IntSerializerFn
implicit val strSerizlizer = StringSerializerFn
```

However, I tried something like this and then tried mapping over the `Keys` `HList` with a `Poly1` that takes an `implicit SerializerFn`, but I ran into similar issues when trying to work with a generic `HLists`.

Comment: I fear I'm missing something - did you try adding an `implicit ser: Serializer[ ReprA, ReprB]` argument to `def toSerializedKeys`? In fact, why can't `Serializer.toBufs` be the function presented to users?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Scala3 (aka dotty), [here is a simple solution](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IrhpJFqRQBel7ELas0gYjg) using stdlib only for your purpose:

```
import scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf as PF
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

trait SerializerFn[T]:
  def toBytes(t: T): ByteBuffer

object StringSerializerFn extends SerializerFn[String]:
  override def toBytes(t: String): ByteBuffer = ???

object IntSerializerFn extends SerializerFn[Int]:
  override def toBytes(t: Int): ByteBuffer = ???

case class SI(key1: String, key2: Int)

case class SII(key1: String, key2: Int, key3: Int)

def toSerializedKeys[K <: Product, S <: Tuple](keys: K, sers: S)
                                              (using pf: PF[K], ev: S <:< Tuple.Map[pf.MirroredElemTypes, SerializerFn]): Unit = {}

// success
toSerializedKeys(SI("a", 1), (StringSerializerFn, IntSerializerFn))
toSerializedKeys(SII("a", 1, 2), (StringSerializerFn, IntSerializerFn, IntSerializerFn))

// compile fail
// toSerializedKeys(SI("a", 1), (StringSerializerFn, StringSerializerFn))
// toSerializedKeys(SII("a", 1, 2), (IntSerializerFn, IntSerializerFn, IntSerializerFn))
```

Comment: `HList` is from Shapeless 2, so hardly this is Scala 3.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just missed evidence `serializer: Serializer[ReprA, ReprB]` in

```
def toSerializedKeys[ReprA <: HList, ReprB <: HList](
  keys: ReprA,
  fns:  ReprB
): List[ByteBuffer] =
  Serializer.toBufs(keys)(fns)
```

So just replace this with

```
def toSerializedKeys[ReprA <: HList, ReprB <: HList](
  keys: ReprA,
  fns:  ReprB
)(implicit serializer: Serializer[ReprA, ReprB]): List[ByteBuffer] =
  Serializer.toBufs(keys)(fns)
```

Then

```
case class Keys(key1: String, key2: Int)

val keys = Keys("Foo", 2)
val keyDescriptor = (StringSerializer, IntSerializer)

toSerializedKeys(keys, keyDescriptor)
```

compiles (as expected) and

```
val keys = Keys("Foo", 2)
val keyDescriptor = (StringSerializer, StringSerializer)

toSerializedKeys(keys, keyDescriptor)
```

doesn't (as expected).

Just noticed that **Alec** advised the same in comments.